# Nginx map module regex from include file not working

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, url-mapping

I am trying to redirect some urls to a different document path. My configuration file is as follows

###### /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf

```
    map_hash_max_size 2048;
    map_hash_bucket_size 128;
    map $uri $new {
            include list_4;
    }
    resolver  127.0.0.1;
    server {
            listen         81;
            server_name abcexample.com;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/abcexample-access.log main;
            error_log  /var/log/nginx/abcexample-error.log;
            location / {
                    if ($new) {
                      rewrite ^ $new redirect;
                    }
                  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            }
     }
```

########### /etc/nginx/list_4

```
/abc/1.html /abc/hello;
/max/1.html /max/;
~^/xyz/(?<abc>.*)$ /xyz/123;
~^/kkkk/abcdef(?<abc>.*)$ /tttt/bbbbb/jjjj$abc;
~^/kaka/(?<abc>.*)$ /tata/$abc;
```

Note: 
line 1,2 and 3 redirects are working fine. 
But line 4 and 5 are not working.

```
root@Hell1:~# curl -I abcexample.com/kkkk/abcef111.html 
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2017 07:08:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Location: http://abcdexample.com/tttt/bbbbb/jjjj$abc
Connection: keep-alive
```

My Question is:
What changes do I have to do in list_4 file to get results as follows

```
Location: http://abcdexample.com/news/bbbbb/jjjj111.html
```

Comment: Although `map` is capable of using named captures, you cannot use those to define the resulting constant value (which is a shame). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: tested on nginx/1.11.13 with positive result. Named captures works as expected.

Comment: @Deadooshka: Thanks :) I am using nginx-1.10.2 on CentOS 7.3. And of course I can/will not upgrade nginx on all my servers. So I am going forward with editing nginx conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Combining variables and text is only available since version 1.11.0.

> The resulting value can contain text, variable (0.9.0), and their combination (1.11.0).

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

> Changes with nginx 1.11.0 --- 24 May 2016
>
> *) Feature: the "map" directive supports combinations of multiple variables as resulting values.

http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES